# How can I add new selectbox option with value of its label with jquery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, append, label

I need to get a placeholder for predefined select box (can't add first option by myself because it is taken from system that my client is using - Pardot).

I added placeholders for input fields with Jquery, and I can add it if there is a single dropdown. But I need to make it automatic if there are more than one.

This is my curent code:

```js
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
    var i = labels.length;
    while (i--) {
        var label = labels.item(i);
        var text = label.textContent;
        label.parentNode.classList.contains("required") && (text += "*");
        label.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("placeholder", text);
    };
    $('.select').append( '<option disabled selected hidden>'+'Industry</option>' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="field-label" for="133191_52859pi_133191_52859">Industry222</label>
<select name="133191_52859pi_133191_52859" id="133191_52859pi_133191_52859" class="select" onchange="" >
    <option value="664141" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="664143">Account Source</option>
    <option value="664145">Ad Unit of Interest</option>
    <option value="664147">Advertising</option>
    <option value="664149">Aerospace &amp; Defense</option>
    <option value="664151">Agency</option>
    <option value="664153">Agriculture</option>
</select>
```

In this example first option in select box is added by myself with

```
$('.select').append( '<option disabled selected hidden>'+'Industry</option>' );
```

Can someone help me to make it automatic. Best solution it will be to pull content from label and to add new option with value of that field. And to make loop for every dropdown if there are more than one.

EDIT: First part of js code is for adding placeholders in input fields (it adds it to select, maybe I could pull value of placeholder and put it in new option).

Comment: Found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085698/add-text-to-option-from-the-label-with-pure-js

Answer (score 0):

```js
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("p.pd-text label, p.pd-select label, p.pd-textarea label");
var i = labels.length;
while (i--) {
  var label = labels.item(i);
  var text = label.textContent;
  label.parentNode.classList.contains("required") && (text += " *");
  var nextElement = label.nextElementSibling;
 
  if (nextElement) {
    if (nextElement.tagName == 'SELECT') {
      nextElement.options[0].text = text;
    } else {
      nextElement.setAttribute("placeholder", text);
    }
    label.parentNode.removeChild(label);
  }
}
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.errors, .no-label');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-field industry pd-select required">
  <label class="field-label" for="133191_52859pi_133191_52859">Industry222</label>
  <select name="133191_52859pi_133191_52859" id="133191_52859pi_133191_52859" class="select" onchange="">
        <option value="664141" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="664143">Account Source</option>
        <option value="664145">Ad Unit of Interest</option>
        <option value="664147">Advertising</option>
        <option value="664149">Aerospace &amp; Defense</option>
        <option value="664151">Agency</option>
        <option value="664153">Agriculture</option>
    </select>
</p>
```